# How to avoid from exception on providing null model reference in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In this Model "HomePageModel" contains three sub-models named as "JoinedClasses","RequestedClasses" and "tbl_Student". If a user still didn't have joined a class then its object passed should be null as shown in fig. and I have checked through if-condition to avoid from exception but it always throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", how to avoid from this exception on null reference provision

[image]

Comment: null doesn't have a .Equals method. You'll have to use if(Model.JoinedClasses != null) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Equals()` cannot be used to compare with `null` values, because if an object is null, it won't have the method `.Equals()`! In your case, the method itself is throwing the Nullreference exception.

Just change to:

```
@if(Model.JoinedClasses != null) {
 //...code
}
```